# I would like to do dynamic div height in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I would like to do dynamic Div sizes with this code. I would like the div's size to increase or decrease with the plus and minus buttons. What shlould I do>

This is my code:

Javascript:

```
window.onload=function(){
    var output = document.getElementById('output');
    var i=1;
    //var val="";
    while(i<=3)
    {

        if(!document.getElementById('timedrpact'+i))
        {
            var ele = document.createElement("div");
            ele.setAttribute("id",i);
            ele.setAttribute("class","inner");
            //ele.innerHTML="hi "+i;

            var bplus = document.createElement('button');
            bplus.setAttribute('content', 'plus');
            bplus.setAttribute('class', 'bplus');
            bplus.setAttribute('onClick', 'plusDiv('+i+');');
            bplus.style.setProperty ("background-color", "green", null);
            bplus.style.setProperty ("color", "green", null);
            bplus.innerHTML = '!!!!';

            var bminus = document.createElement('button');
            bminus.setAttribute('content', 'minus');
            bminus.setAttribute('onClick', 'minusDiv('+i+');');
            bminus.setAttribute('class', 'bminus');
            bminus.style.setProperty ("background-color", "red", null);
            bminus.style.setProperty ("color", "red", null);
            bminus.innerHTML = '!!';

            output.appendChild(ele);
            ele.appendChild(bplus);
            ele.appendChild(bminus);

        }
        i++;


    }
};

function plusDiv(id) {
    var el = document.getElementById(i);
    var height = el.offsetHeight;
    var newHeight = height + 200;
    el.style.height = newHeight + 'px';
}

function minusDiv() {
    var el = document.getElementById(i);
    var height = el.offsetHeight;
    var newHeight = height - 200;
    el.style.height = newHeight + 'px';
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="output" class="out">

</div>
```

CSS

```
div {
 border: 1px dotted red;
 padding: 10px;    
}
```

When i click on button it doesnt do anything.

I would like to rezise this Div's sizes with the plus and minus buttons.

Any ideas?

Comment: post only relevant code. the code with background is not relevant

Comment: The easiest way to manipulate the DOM like that is to use jQuery. Just go to their websites and check out some tutorials on how to manipulate the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

you have mistakes in your code try this

```
function plusDiv(id) {
        var el = document.getElementById(id);
        var height = el.offsetHeight;
        var newHeight = height + 200;
        el.style.height = newHeight + 'px';
    }

    function minusDiv(id) {
        var el = document.getElementById(id);
        var height = el.offsetHeight;
        var newHeight = height - 200;
        el.style.height = newHeight + 'px';
    }
```

---

Answer (score 0):

The reason it doesn't do anything is because your plusDiv function takes in "id" but then tries to use "i" and the minusDiv method doesn't take anything in.

This seems to work for me:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Div Height Test</title>
    </head>    
    <body>
        <style type="text/css">
            div {
                border: 1px dotted red;
                padding: 10px;
            }
        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            window.onload = function () {
                var output = document.getElementById('output');
                var i = 1;
                //var val="";
                while (i <= 3) {

                    if (!document.getElementById('timedrpact' + i)) {
                        var ele = document.createElement("div");
                        ele.setAttribute("id", i);
                        ele.setAttribute("class", "inner");
                        //ele.innerHTML="hi "+i;

                        var bplus = document.createElement('button');
                        bplus.setAttribute('content', 'plus');
                        bplus.setAttribute('class', 'bplus');
                        bplus.setAttribute('onClick', 'plusDiv(' + i + ');');
                        bplus.style.setProperty("background-color", "green", null);
                        bplus.style.setProperty("color", "green", null);
                        bplus.innerHTML = '!!!!';

                        var bminus = document.createElement('button');
                        bminus.setAttribute('content', 'minus');
                        bminus.setAttribute('onClick', 'minusDiv(' + i + ');');
                        bminus.setAttribute('class', 'bminus');
                        bminus.style.setProperty("background-color", "red", null);
                        bminus.style.setProperty("color", "red", null);
                        bminus.innerHTML = '!!';

                        output.appendChild(ele);
                        ele.appendChild(bplus);
                        ele.appendChild(bminus);

                    }
                    i++;


                }
            };

            function plusDiv(i) {
                var el = document.getElementById(i);
                var height = el.offsetHeight;
                var newHeight = height + 200;
                el.style.height = newHeight + 'px';
            }

            function minusDiv(i) {
                var el = document.getElementById(i);
                var height = el.offsetHeight;
                var newHeight = height - 200;
                el.style.height = newHeight + 'px';
            }
        </script>
        <div id="output" class="out">

        </div>
    </body>

</html>
```